# Using Fulltext in MYSQL, are wildcards expensive?

Tags: mysql, database, full-text-search

I am working on a MySQL search query where I would like incomplete strings to find matches such as:

Search term: "Fi Res", which should find: "Find Result".

I have found a few related questions that tend to answer "use Fulltext". Simply using fulltext doesn't match partial terms, but it seems to work with wildcards, so this (appears to) work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH (field) AGAINST ('Fi*Res*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

And a quick solution seems to be just replace the spaces in a query with *.

I'm wondering if there's some reason not to do this, and if so, what (better) implementations should I be looking at?

Also, in this case it's a smaller database table (< 20,000 rows) and the strings to be searched are short (max 255 length).

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are just substitution of words in 'values' u r searching.. for example google search is kind of wildcard. so u can use '%' wild card for searching..!